# How many buildings in tornado prone-areas have storm shelters?

Tags: tornado

I did a quick search, but couldn't pull any statistics from it.  On tornado risk days, many I interact with in Oklahoma become concerned or panicked that they don't have a shelter.  I am guessing the percentage of people with shelters is actually pretty low, and in such situations a statistic like that might be encouraging to folks.  Does anybody know where I can find such statistics?

Comment: We can include safe rooms in this too (if that's included in any metrics).

Comment: I did some searching for this too, and wasn't able to come up with much. If you really wanted to do the research, I would try calling the city or county government offices of medium sized cities in the Tornado Belt, like [Grand Island](http://www.grand-island.com/your-government/emergency-management/severe-weather-information), Hall County, Nebraska; or [Lawton](http://www.cityof.lawton.ok.us/tornadoinfo.htm), Comanche County, Oklahoma.

Comment: I'm definitely considering doing such.

Comment: It's not fully what I have looked for here, but somebody did recently do a fair bit of legwork to put together a list of public shelters: https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?ll=38.19167637785379%2C-95.62149400051587&z=5&mid=1CmSTiHw8ik73XO40MhMSeNdejCl9zAcF  I would think there's some dangers of small shelters becoming overloaded, so wouldn't rely on it too heavily given it's somewhat limited information.  But it's a start on that, FINALLY.

Answer (score 1):

Have you perhaps contact the National Weather Service or FEMA about that ? If not, then maybe find out from real estate that they might have data for each houses in your state. They may have the data or not, but it is hard to know. All I know is that each state has different types of soils that can or can't built storm shelter. I heard in Texas almost 1/2 of the buildings there do not have a storm shelter, because the soil in Texas are not strong enough to withstand against the flooding. That kind of thing ...

I do not know if you have seen this, https://stateimpact.npr.org/oklahoma/2013/09/27/mapped-which-oklahoma-schools-have-storm-shelters/

http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0104/storm.html

Another one is the reason why an individual passed away from flooding in a storm shelter
http://mashable.com/2015/05/07/oklahoma-city-storm-fatality/#KGEHNAxU5sqq